# Are there anyway to get original file name from dataURI

Tags: javascript, quill

I used quilljs editor for my project. When I upload image (name is angular.jpeg) via editor, it embed as base64 image like

`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/......">`

I need to upload this image to server. So I changed that dataURI to blob.

I am curious that are there anyway to get original file name (angular.jpeg) from dataURI?

Comment: no dataURI only contains image data. You have to extract name with your own logic like from imagepath

Comment: Thanks @GauravChaudhary